# Logic for firing events when person attacks other person?

Tags: python, events, logic

I have a class `Person` which looks like this:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, health, damage):
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage

    def attack(self, victim):
        victim.hurt(self.damage)

    def hurt(self, damage):
        self.health -= damage
```

I also have an `Event` class that holds listener functions which get called when the event fires.
Let's add few events for the instances:

```
    def __init__(self, health, damage):
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage
        self.event_attack = Event() # fire when person attacks
        self.event_hurt = Event() # fire when person takes damage
        self.event_kill = Event() # fire when person kills someone
        self.event_death = Event() # fire when person dies
```

Now then, I would like my events to send certain data to the listener functions with `**kwargs`.
The problem is, I want all four events to send both `attacker` and `victim`.
This makes it somewhat complicated, I would have to give `attacker` as a parameter to `hurt()`-method and then again raise events of `attacker` in `victim`'s `hurt()`-method:

```
def attack(self, victim):
    self.event_attack.fire(victim=victim, attacker=self)
    victim.hurt(self, self.damage)

def hurt(self, attacker, damage):
    self.health -= damage
    self.event_hurt.fire(attacker=attacker, victim=self)
    if self.health <= 0:
        attacker.event_kill.fire(attacker=attacker, victim=self)
        self.event_death.fire(attacker=attacker, victim=self)
```

I don't think I should even give `attacker` as a parameter for `hurt()`-method, since it's not needed for hurting, only for raising the event.
Also, raising attacker's `event_kill`-event inside victim's `hurt()`-method is hardly against encapsulation.

How should I design these events so that they would follow encapsulation and generally make more sense?

Comment: Do they need to be class methods?

Comment: `they`? Listeners don't, they can be anything. But obviously it's Person who attacks and Person gets hurt, so `attack` and `hurt` have to be methods.

Comment: +1 for most intriguing question title of the day.

Comment: Logic for firing upvotes when person comments on other person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for a very general answer on the basis of a very specific situation.  I'd like to give a more vague answer which forgets a little about your current concrete situation.  So maybe this is too general to be applied to your situation directly.

In [Tubmud](http://www.tubmud.de) we designed an event system which we redesigned more than once to fit all our needs, and still it could not handle everything we could think of.  But your example is very well-known and would have found a proper representation there.

The system was based on a global event server (a singleton, GES) to which all listeners for events would register and all event distribution would we handled by the GES.  No direct calling of other object would be involved.

If a person would apply an attack on another person, it would simply tell the GES that an attack event is sent.  The GES would then (based on the location of the event happening, but that's out of scope) send that event to all attack-listeners involved (guardian angles, victim, attacker, weapons, …).

Now the victim person would also receive that event (would be called by the GES), would then as a reaction schedule a hurt-event (again by only telling the GES about that event).  Whether or not the source of that hurting would be mentioned in that event data is merely a design decision (maybe you don't want to give hurting-listeners like healing-spells or similar any means of finding out who is the attacker, for whatever reason).  In Tubmud we went for sending as much information as possible and didn't experience any drawbacks this way.

The victim person now would be called again by the GES to receive that hurt-event it sent itself (because maybe some other listener would change sth in the hurting, for instance reduce the hurt due to pain-blockers).  Reacting on it, it would reduce its health actually.

If that health reduction led to a death, it would then send a death-event because in our understanding, dying is the more physical thing to happen (and that we let happen first).  That again would be an event sent via the GES and received by the victim person again.  If you decided not to mention the attacker in the hurt-event, then it would not appear in the death-event as well.  So maybe you now would decide differently ;-)

Finally, now, killing is not a physical event in my understanding, it is rather an interpretation of what happens.  If an attack event leads to a damage and this to a death, then this is a kill.  So, strictly speaking, the proper way of detecting this would be a kind of all-seeing judge which just notices all these events and based on their outcome decides to then send a kill-event.

I'm not sure if these thoughts help you in any way.  I just post this as a report on how we did this.

So, concerning your question:

If you design a simulation of the physical world and want to be able to *decide* after a series of events what they *mean*, don't be too eager in encapsulate data by trying to stick it only where it belongs.  The attacker might not seem important during the hurt-event, so you might be tempted to omit it, but as soon as the outcome shall be interpreted in its wholeness, missing data is annoying.  After all, in real life the police will probably find that missing data as well (so in fact in real life the information who did the damage typically *is* present in the hurting).

Comment: Well, this did not directly answer my question, but I think it helped more than a direct answer would have. I'm not gonna accept just yet, if someone comes up with a better answer (doubt it), but thanks for your great answer, I *really* appreciate it! :)

Comment: Loved writing it :)  And you can change you acceptance later again, so AFAIK accepting an answer is not final.